# jquery loading message before go to page 2 from page 1

Tags: jquery, load, loading

I want to show a loading message (when the user click in a link from my nav for example) with a waiting message or a gif when the 2nd page is loading.

I want to do this because the second page can take a moment before showing its content.
I don 't want to show a blank page.
How can i do this with Jquery ?

A perfect example :
After adding a product, go to this page and click the pink button (*valider mon panier)* :

[sohome's cart page](https://www.sohome.fr/commande/panier.aspx)

thank you and sorry for my english...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AJAX to load the second page you can make use of the call back functions such as beforeSend:function() and complete:function(). Initially make a gif image invisible, then when making an AJAX call you can make the gif image visible in the beforeSend: function(). You would then hide the gif image when the other page has finished loading in the complete:function();.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Hope this was helpful!

Comment: i don t know if i have to use AJAX but i want to display the correct url in the browser. Just like in the example in my post (sohome.fr)

Comment: Well that means that on page2 before loading you would need to put the gif you want to be seen. On the example they just place a box before the the browser goes on to the next page. That isn't really a perfect example.